# Add Custom Properties for RequestTelemetry of the Azure Function (v3) binding to BlobTrigger

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I want to add Custom Properties to the RequestTelemetry generated for the Azure function(V3) written in C#.

Thanks to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848971/add-custom-properties-for-requesttelemetry-of-the-azure-function-v3), I managed to achieve this for the function with HttpTrigger binding.

```
var requestTelemetry = req.HttpContext?.Features.Get<RequestTelemetry>();
requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("MyProp", "Some value");
```

However, when I try to do same thing for another function with BlobTrigger binding, it became confusing. The first challenge is:

> How to get current `RequestTelemetry` in a function that is using
> BlobTrigger binding?

In a function with HttpTrigger binding, the function is injected with `HttpRequest` parameter

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = "upload/{name}")] HttpRequest req,
            string name,
            ILogger log,
            ExecutionContext context)
        {  
  ...
}
```

So we can get current RequestTelemetry using `HttpRequest`. However, what about a function with BlobTrigger:

```
    [FunctionName("Create-Thumbnail")]
            public async Task CreateThumbnail([BlobTrigger("input/{name}",  Source = BlobTriggerSource.EventGrid, Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream image,
                IDictionary<string,string> metadata,
                string name,
                ExecutionContext context)
            { 
  ...
}
```

I have tried injecting `HttpRequest` and using same way as HttpTrigger function. But it didn't work.

After hours extensive research, I couldn't find any documentation or posts that are related to this question.

Can anyone provide some tips for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no http request when using a blob trigger. You can still add custom properties to the telemetry generated during the execution by setting properties like this:

```cs
// The current telemetry item gets a property. 
// Useful if the function is not triggered by an http request
Activity.Current.AddTag("setUsingTag", "setUsingTag");

// Subsequent telemetry gets this property attached
Activity.Current.AddBaggage("setUsingActivityBaggage", "setUsingActivityBaggage");
```

When using Baggage instead of a Tag the custom property is added to all telemetry generated during the execution, like dependency calls etc.

See also [this github thread](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/562#issuecomment-696236846). It also [mentions](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/562#issuecomment-891274333) there might be a bug introduced in a later version of AI that might force you to downgrade AI for this to work.

---

Thanks to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7278), this is finally working after downgrading System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource to version 4.6

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="4.6.0" />
```

Comment: Hi Peter, I have tried your suggestion. But it didn't work, even with downgrading the Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Logging.ApplicationInsights to 3.0.14. I got "System.NullReferenceException"

Comment: @codigube I've seen this one in a while in a non-production environment. Try deploy the code using `Activity.Current?.AddXX`, does it then work when deployed to Azure?

Comment: Hi Peter, I did use `Activity.Current?.AddXX` as well. Then the error was gone but no custom property was added either. That's why I wonder why Activity.Current is null. I made a new post to ask for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68867641/activity-current-is-null-in-azure-function-with-blobtrigger

Comment: Thanks to this GitHub issue (https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/7278), this is finally working after downgrading System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource to to version 4.6